# Can't delete some symbolic links on HFS volume (Mac OS X 10.7.2)

Tags: osx-lion, rm

I can't seem to delete a pile of files; what all these files have in common is as follows:

- They're all symbolic links, or otherwise parenting directories
- They're all owned by an unmapped user and group

That is:

```
sh-3.2# find . -type l -exec ls -ld {} \;
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1001  1001  14 10 Apr  2011 ./kernel/kernel -> linux-2.6.38.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1001  1001  15 25 May  2011 ./kernel/logo/logo.ppm -> skull-black.ppm
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1001  1001  19  2 Sep 15:12 ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/default/.libs/libdefault.so.0 -> libdefault.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1001  1001  17  2 Sep 15:12 ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/nico2/.libs/libnico2.so -> libnico2.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1001  1001  15 15 Jul  2011 ./redhat/BUILD/libg15-1.2.7/.libs/libg15.so -> libg15.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1001  1001  15 15 Jul  2011 ./redhat/BUILD/libg15-1.2.7/.libs/libg15.so.1 -> libg15.so.1.0.0
sh-3.2# find . -type d -exec ls -ld {} \;
drwxrwxrwx  4 root  wheel  136 23 Jan 10:55 .
drwxrwxrwx  3 root  wheel  136 22 Jan 22:33 ./kernel
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  wheel  102 22 Jan 22:31 ./kernel/logo
drwxrwxrwx  3 root  wheel  102 23 Jan 10:55 ./redhat
drwxrwxrwx  4 root  wheel  136 23 Jan 10:55 ./redhat/BUILD
drwxrwxrwx  3 root  wheel  102 23 Jan 10:55 ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git
drwxrwxrwx  4 root  wheel  136 23 Jan 10:55 ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display
drwxrwxrwx  3 root  wheel  102 22 Jan 22:21 ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/default
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  wheel  102 22 Jan 22:33 ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/default/.libs
drwxrwxrwx  3 root  wheel  102 22 Jan 22:21 ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/nico2
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  wheel  102 23 Jan 11:00 ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/nico2/.libs
drwxrwxrwx  3 root  wheel  102 22 Jan 22:21 ./redhat/BUILD/libg15-1.2.7
drwx------  2 root  wheel  136 22 Jan 22:21 ./redhat/BUILD/libg15-1.2.7/.libs
sh-3.2# find . -not -type d -a -not -type l -exec ls -ld {} \;
sh-3.2#
```

As for the deletion:

```
sh-3.2# ls -l ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/default/.libs/libdefault.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1001  1001  19  2 Sep 15:12 ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/default/.libs/libdefault.so.0 -> libdefault.so.0.0.0
sh-3.2# rm -f ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/default/.libs/libdefault.so.0
sh-3.2# ls -l ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/default/.libs/libdefault.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1001  1001  19  2 Sep 15:12 ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/default/.libs/libdefault.so.0 -> libdefault.so.0.0.0
sh-3.2# rm  ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/default/.libs/libdefault.so.0 
rm: ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/default/.libs/libdefault.so.0: No such file or directory
sh-3.2# ls -li !$
ls -li ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/default/.libs/libdefault.so.0
282892 lrwxrwxrwx  1 1001  1001  19  2 Sep 15:12 ./redhat/BUILD/gol-git/display/default/.libs/libdefault.so.0 -> libdefault.so.0.0.0
sh-3.2#
```

Mount options for the HFS volume in question are as follows:

- hfs, local, nodev, nosuid

Answer (score 0):

Those are symbolic links. Are you wanting to delete the link or the original file? (Either way, rm should work.) You could try `unlink`, but it's the more dangerous option. You could also try `sudo rm`, although I'm not sure if that will have any effect on your situation. A final option would be to try changing the owner using `sudo chown`. (But again, this may not work with files that think they don't exist...)